# MySQL- MAX COUNT multiple groups

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
╒═══════════╤════════════╤════════════╕
│ iddmp2g_2 │ A_BCF_name │ A_BTS_name │
╞═══════════╪════════════╪════════════╡
│ 1         │ CAR.Inem   │ CAR.Inem_A │
├───────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│ 2         │ CAR.Inem   │ CAR.Inem_A │
├───────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│ 3         │ CAR.Inem   │ CAR.Inem_A │
├───────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│ 4         │ CAR.Inem   │ CAR.Inem_A │
├───────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│ 5         │ CAR.Inem   │ CAR.Inem_B │
├───────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│ 6         │ CAR.Inem   │ CAR.Inem_B │
├───────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│ 7         │ CAR.Inem   │ CAR.Inem_B │
├───────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│ 8         │ CAR.Inem   │ CAR.Inem_1 │
├───────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│ 9         │ CAR.Inem   │ CAR.Inem_1 │
├───────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│ 10        │ CAR.Inem   │ CAR.Inem_1 │
├───────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│ 11        │ CAR.Inem   │ CAR.Inem_2 │
├───────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│ 12        │ CAR.Inem   │ CAR.Inem_2 │
└───────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

if i apply the following query to the table i get:

```
SELECT A_BCF_name, COUNT(A_BTS_name) from dmp2g_2
group by A_BCF_name, A_BTS_name
```

result:

```
╔════════════╤════════════╤═══════════════════╗
║ A_BCF_name │ A_BTS_name │ COUNT(A_BTS_name) ║
╠════════════╪════════════╪═══════════════════╣
║ CAR.Inem   │ CAR.Inem_A │ 4                 ║
╟────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────╢
║ CAR.Inem   │ CAR.Inem_B │ 3                 ║
╟────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────╢
║ CAR.Inem   │ CAR.Inem_1 │ 3                 ║
╟────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────╢
║ CAR.Inem   │ CAR.Inem_2 │ 2                 ║
╚════════════╧════════════╧═══════════════════╝
```

The next aproach is to get two kind of groups of A_BTS_name based on the last character (number or letter)like this:

```
SELECT A_BCF_name, A_BTS_name, COUNT( A_BTS_name ) 
FROM dmp2g_2
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(A_BTS_name,'_',-1) REGEXP '[0-9]+' /*getting only records that end in a number*/
GROUP BY A_BCF_name, A_BTS_name
```

output:

```
╔════════════╤════════════╤═══════════════════╗
║ A_BCF_name │ A_BTS_name │ COUNT(A_BTS_name) ║
╠════════════╪════════════╪═══════════════════╣
║ CAR.Inem   │ CAR.Inem_1 │ 3                 ║
╟────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────╢
║ CAR.Inem   │ CAR.Inem_2 │ 2                 ║
╚════════════╧════════════╧═══════════════════╝
```

Getting records that end in a letter or char.

```
SELECT A_BCF_name, A_BTS_name, COUNT( A_BTS_name ) 
FROM dmp2g_2
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(A_BTS_name,'_',-1) REGEXP '[A-Za-z]' /*filter records that ends in a letter*/
GROUP BY A_BCF_name, A_BTS_name
```

output:

```
╔════════════╤════════════╤═══════════════════╗
║ A_BCF_name │ A_BTS_name │ COUNT(A_BTS_name) ║
╠════════════╪════════════╪═══════════════════╣
║ CAR.Inem   │ CAR.Inem_A │ 4                 ║
╟────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────╢
║ CAR.Inem   │ CAR.Inem_B │ 3                 ║
+────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────+
```

at this point all is OK.

My question is how to get the max count of each kind of group? i need to get max count between  CAR.Inem_A and CAR.Inem_B and max count between CAR.Inem_1 and CAR.Inem_2. The result should like this:

```
╔════════════╤════════════════════════╤════════════════════════╗
║ A_BCF_name │ MAX(A_BTS_name_number) │ MAX(A_BTS_name_letter) ║
╠════════════╪════════════════════════╪════════════════════════╣
║ CAR.Inem   │ 3                      │ 4                      ║
╚════════════╧════════════════════════╧════════════════════════╝
```

I appreciate any help

thanks

Comment: What is `numTRX850` and `numTRX1900`? In your sample data it does not exist. But in your expected result you have those columns.

Comment: You seem to have a lot of duplication. Where's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: @Viki888 is an alias of the result of the max count

Comment: @Strawberry my primary key is a column named iddmp2g_2--- INT(11) and i have a index on  A_BCF_name

Comment: @Leo99 Your question is not clear. Your sample data and sample expected result does not seem to match.

Comment: There is no column with that name here - and your naming policy is something to behold.

Comment: @Viki888 i reformulated the question, i hope you can understand what i need, i apreciate yoour help

Comment: @Viki888 i reformulated the question, i hope you can understand what i need, i apreciate yoour help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a query that gives you the information you're asking for but the results are arranged in a more query-friendly way.

```
select
 t3.A_BCF_name,
 t3.record_type,
 max(t3.record_count) as max_record_count
from
  (
   select
    t2.A_BCF_name,
    t2.A_BTS_name,
    t2.record_type,
   count(t2.record_type) record_count
   from 
   (
    select
     t1.iddmp2g_2,
     t1.A_BCF_name,
     t1.A_BTS_name,
     case when SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.A_BTS_name,'_',-1) REGEXP '[A-Za-z]' then 'letter' else 'number' end as record_type
    from dmp2g_2 as t1
   ) as t2
   group by t2.A_BCF_name, t2.A_BTS_name, t2.record_type
 ) as t3
group by t3.A_BCF_name, t3.record_type;
```

There are 2 nested queries here. The deepest nested query is simply the table rendered again with an extra `record_type` column dynamically added. The next nested query selects from the above nested query aggregating on the record type and counting all the groups. And finally, the outer query aggregates on the `A_BCF_name` and `record_type` and chooses the max count of each group.

Here is code I wrote to generate sample data to verify the query produces the desired result:

```
create table dmp2g_2 (
 iddmp2g_2 int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
 A_BCF_name varchar(32) not null,
 A_BTS_name varchar(32) not null,
 index (A_BCF_name),
 index (A_BTS_name)
) engine=innodb;

insert into dmp2g_2 (A_BCF_name, A_BTS_name) values
('CAR.Inem', 'CAR.Inem_A'),
('CAR.Inem', 'CAR.Inem_A'),
('CAR.Inem', 'CAR.Inem_A'),
('CAR.Inem', 'CAR.Inem_A'),
('CAR.Inem', 'CAR.Inem_B'),
('CAR.Inem', 'CAR.Inem_B'),
('CAR.Inem', 'CAR.Inem_B'),
('CAR.Inem', 'CAR.Inem_1'),
('CAR.Inem', 'CAR.Inem_1'),
('CAR.Inem', 'CAR.Inem_1'),
('CAR.Inem', 'CAR.Inem_2'),
('CAR.Inem', 'CAR.Inem_2');
```

And the result:

```
mysql> select
    ->  t3.A_BCF_name,
    ->  t3.record_type,
    ->  max(t3.record_count) as max_record_count
    -> from
    ->   (
    ->    select
    ->     t2.A_BCF_name,
    ->     t2.A_BTS_name,
    ->     t2.record_type,
    ->    count(t2.record_type) record_count
    ->    from 
    ->    (
    ->     select
    ->      t1.iddmp2g_2,
    ->      t1.A_BCF_name,
    ->      t1.A_BTS_name,
    ->      case when SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.A_BTS_name,'_',-1) REGEXP '[A-Za-z]' then 'letter' else 'number' end as record_type
    ->     from dmp2g_2 as t1
    ->    ) as t2
    ->    group by t2.A_BCF_name, t2.A_BTS_name, t2.record_type
    ->  ) as t3
    -> group by t3.A_BCF_name, t3.record_type;
+------------+-------------+------------------+
| A_BCF_name | record_type | max_record_count |
+------------+-------------+------------------+
| CAR.Inem   | letter      |                4 |
| CAR.Inem   | number      |                3 |
+------------+-------------+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```